# How to replace bitmapData.copyPixels() with bitmapData.draw()

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, draw, tile, bitmapdata

I'm trying to draw a level of my game using a tileset and a xml with the info. It works using copyPixels, but some tiles need to be flipped before they are drawn, so for that I need to use `draw()` instead of `copyPixels()`, but I can't get it to work. This is how I use copyPixes:

```
rectangleSelection = (desiredTile.x, desiredTile.y, tileWidth, tileHeight);

bmpData.copyPixels(tileset.bitmapData, rectangleSelection, new Point(pt.x, pt.y));
//pt.x and pt.y = tile location to be drawn().
```

How can I do the same thing using the `bitmapData.draw()` method? I just can't make it work.

Comment: I wouldn't use `draw` and `copyPixels` at the same time. I would use `draw` upfront to create the flipped versions of your tiles first, and then continue using `copyPixels`.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do that just the way you said.